# How to build a multi component application?

Tags: npm, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have an OpenUI5 project with the structure depicted below. It contains one RootComponent that displays two other separate Components (UserComponent and AdminComponent).

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ RootComponent/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ ui5.yaml
│  ├─ webapp/
│  |  ├─ manifest.json
│  |  ├─ Component.js
├─ UserComponent/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ ui5.yaml
│  ├─ webapp/
│  |  ├─ manifest.json
│  |  ├─ Component.js
├─ AdminComponent/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ ui5.yaml
│  ├─ webapp/
│  |  ├─ manifest.json
│  |  ├─ Component.js
├─ package.json
├─ README.md
```

However, when I run `npm install` and then build the RootComponent project using the [UI5 CLI](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/v3/pages/CLI/), the UserComponent and AdminComponent are not included in the build output. The console prints the error:

```
**** error: missing module my/app/user/Component.js
```

I am following the example provided in an [official sample repository](https://github.com/flovogt/ui5con20-ui5-routing/tree/main/demo). When I locally build this sample project using `ui5 build --all`, the dependent components are built into the `resources` folder of the output directory, as depicted here.

---

[image: Folder Structure with dependent Components]

---

When I execute the same command in my own RootComponent project, the resulting resources folder contains the dependencies from the `sap.*` packages, but **not** the UserComponent and the AdminComponent. Thus, when I run the RootComponent on a web server, I am getting 404 errors.

My truncated configuration files are listed below:

**RootComponent/package.json**

```
{
    "name": "my-app-root",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "ui5 build self-contained --all --dest=../../webapp --clean-dest",
        // ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "my-app-user": "file:../UserComponent",
        "my-app-admin": "file:../AdminComponent"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**RootComponent/ui5.yaml**

```
specVersion: "3.0"
metadata:
  name: my.app.root
type: application
builder:
  customTasks:
  - name: ui5-tooling-modules-task
    afterTask: replaceVersion
server:
  customMiddleware:
    - name: ui5-middleware-livereload
      afterMiddleware: compression
framework:
  name: OpenUI5
  version: "1.118.0"
```

**RootComponent/webapp/manifest.json**

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "my.app.root",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        // ...
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "rootView": {
            // ...
        },
        "componentUsages": {
            "UserComponent": {
                "name": "my.app.user",
                "settings": {},
                "componentData": {},
                "lazy": true
            },
            "AdminComponent": {
                "name": "my.user.admin",
                "settings": {},
                "componentData": {},
                "lazy": true
            }
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.118.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {}
            },
            "components": {
                "my.app.user": {},
                "my.app.admin": {}
            }
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                // ...
            }
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                // ...
            },
            "routes": [
                // ...
            ],
            "targets": {
                "user": {
                    "type": "Component",
                    "usage": "UserComponent"
                },
                "admin": {
                    "type": "Component",
                    "usage": "AdminComponent"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserComponent/package.json**

```
{
    "name": "pars-web-user",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "ui5 build --clean-dest --all"
        // ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        // ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**UserComponent/webapp/manifest.json**

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",

    "sap.app": {
        "id": "my.app.user",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    },
    // ...
}
```

What do I need in order to successfully include the two dependent Components into the build output? What piece am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. The issue was that the `ui5.yaml` files of the UserComponent and AdminComponent contained the attribute

```
type: application
```

But this attribute should only be set at the RootComponent. The child components should contain the attribute

```
type: library
```

instead. 
After renaming the root folders of UserComponent and AdminComponent from `webapp` into `src`, the build finally worked and the Components were added to the `resources` folder.